# Constructive Proof of Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$g$ is differentiable in $[0,1]$ ,$ f(0)=0=f(1)$ and :
$f(x)g'(x)+g(x)=2 \forall x \in [0,1]$
Prove that $g(x)=2 \forall x \in [0,1]$
I know how to prove this using min max theorem and Fermat's theorem for g.

My question is if the attemp bellow is correct.

By applying Rolle for $g$ in $[0,1]$ we get $ξ_0 \in (0,1):g(ξ_0)=2$.
 Αnd then by Rolle again in $[0,ξ_0]$ and $[ξ_0,1]$ and so on ,  we inductively have  the sequence $\xi _n$ .We also call $K$ the set of its limit point .

Consider the set $S$ containing  $x\in[0,1]$
such that  $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $x=\xi _n\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ or $x\in K$

(Apply Rolle for the set of intervals $(x,y) ,x<y\in S$ such that $\nexists x'\in (x,y)$ with $x'\in S$ . If $\forall (x,y) ,x<y\in S$ $\exists x'\in (x,y)$ with $x'\in S$ we stop.) I call it proposition $P$

If we don't stop then we get a new sequence ${ξ_{1}}_n$

Consider $M$ the set of $x={ξ_{1}}_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the limit points of  ${ξ_{1}}_n$
And $S_1=S\cup M$

INductively we have $S_n= \bigcup_{n}(S_{n-1}\cup M_{n-1})$

$N=\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n$ , $N\subseteq [0,1]$
So for $N$ i can run $P$ 
So we can apply  transfinite induction .So set  $Ξ$ we get from tranfinite induction is dense in $[0,1]$.
Because g is continuous then g is constant.

Comment: I find your style of writing not very comprehensible...

Comment: In particular, it's not very well-organized; you introduce almost one new variable every paragraph; many reasonings seem to be ad-hoc; and you didn't even prove that $\Xi$ is dense.

Comment: The set $Ξ$ we get from tranfinite induction has to have the property that:
$\forall (x,y) ,x<y\in S$ $\exists x'\in (x,y)$ with $x'\in S$ (which is why it $Ξ$ is dense).
Or is this not correct?

Comment: Also, why are you using transfinite induction without setting up the ordinals?

Comment: Why does $\Xi$ have to satisfy that property?

Comment: I fail to infer the set-up of your transfinite induction. What is your well-ordered set?

Comment: How to build up the sequence $\xi_{1n}$? When you were building up $\xi_n$, you only added finitely many elements each time...

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, the problem is:

> Let $\,f,g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, be functions, with $g$ differentiable and $f(0)=f(1)=0$, and suppose that the following equality is satisfied
>   $$
> f(x)g'(x)+g(x)=2, \quad \text{for all $x\in[0,1]$.} \tag{1}
> $$ 
>   Show that $g(x)= 2$, for all $x\in [0,1]$.

*Proof.* Clearly, $g(0)=g(1)=2$. Suppose that $g$ is not constant, in which case it possesses a local extremum in some $x_0\in (0,1)$, where clearly, 
$$g(x_0)\ne 2 \quad \text{and} \quad g'(x_0)=0.$$ But these contradict (1). QED

Answer (score 1):

The $f$ is redundant in the setting of the problem. Let's rephrase it as follows:

> Let $g : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable, such that $g(0) = g(1) = 2$, and $g(x) = 2$ whenever $g'(x) = 0$. Show that for every $x \in [0,1]$ we have $g(x) = 2$.

---

Instead of using propositions, let's use sets. Let $A = \{x \in [0,1] \mid g(x) = 2\}$.

From what you have shown, we know that:

1. $A$ is closed
2. for every distinct $x$ and $y$ in $A$ with $x<y$, there is $c$ such that $x<c<y$ and $c \in A$.

Now, we can forget $g$ entirely and focus on $A$.

---

We have a similar set-up up to this point, but now I really cannot make out your argument, so I can't really tell if your attempt is correct, but here is my proof anyway:

---

Let's show that every $x \in [0,1]$ is in $A$:

Consider $L = \displaystyle \sup (A \cap [0,x])$ and $R = \displaystyle \inf (A \cap [x,1])$ (why do they exist?). We know that $L \le x \le R$.

Since $A$ is closed, $L \in A$ and $R \in A$. If $L < R$, then we can derive a contradiction using $2$, so $L=x=R \in A$.